# Sails.js / Waterline - Create is not a function on model

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am new to both Node.js and the Sails.js framework. I am trying to build a website/application with the framework, but am having trouble getting the model part to work as expected. I have looked at the documentation quite a bit, but still am not able to perform this basic task. I am using the PostgreSQL adapter.

The stack is as follows:

```
TypeError: Fragrance.create is not a function\n    at Object.module.exports.index (/home/kelly/workspace/Hawthorne-Acres/api/controllers/HomeController.js:16:19)\n    at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)\n    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)\n    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)\n    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)\n    at nextRoute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)\n    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)\n    at alwaysAllow (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:224:11)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)\n    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)\n    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)\n    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)\n    at nextRoute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)\n    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)\n    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/cors/clear-headers.js:14:3)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)\n    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)\n    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)"
```

Fragrance.js (located in the api/models folder):

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        fragranceName: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        listings: {
            collection: "listing",
            via: "fragrance"
        }
    }
};
```

The controller that calls the function

```
    /**
 * HomeController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing Homes
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */
var Fragrance = require("../models/Fragrance");

module.exports = {



    /**
     * `HomeController.Index()`
     */
    index: function(req, res) {
        Fragrance.create({ fragranceName: 'Vanilla' }).exec(function(err, rec) {
            console.log(rec.id);
        });
        return res.render("index", { title: "Welcome" });

    },


    /**
     * `HomeController.About()`
     */
    about: function(req, res) {
        console.log("About place");
        return res.render("about", { title: "About" });
    },


    /**
     * `HomeController.Contact()`
     */
    contact: function(req, res) {
        return res.render("contact", { title: "Contact" });
    }
};
```

It is probably something obvious, but I have made an effort to figure it out on my own, just without success. As such, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The models in `model` folder are globally available. You can disable the functionality in `config/globals.js`. So you can drop

`var Fragrance = require("../models/Fragrance");`

Then you can create a record via:

`Fragrance.create` method

or

`sails.models.fragrance.create` method (Notice the model name is in lowercase.)

Personally, I  prefer the second pattern and turning off the availability of models globally.

Comment: Thanks much for both answer and underlying explanation; it is working now.